# Why does streaming video require so much memory?

Tags: memory, video, streaming

I've noticed that Chrome starts discarding tabs when free memory is down to about 1.2 GB.  The only reason I can find for that level of caution is the large amount of RAM required to stream both live and On Demand video.  Sometimes I see an entire GB freed when a movie ends!

That's well under the full size of the video so the player is clearly freeing memory as it goes along.  But why is it so reluctant to do so?  I would expect it to be able to rewind for a few minutes, but 1 GB should be almost a full hour of 1080p video and that seems excessive.  I would much prefer to keep my Chrome tabs intact rather than have the ability to rewind through most of a video.

Comment: Which player are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure of the different types of players available.  I get this problem when watching Amazon Prime, Spectrum streaming video and chess24.com (which is apparently using YouTube).

Comment: To clarify, I use Chrome to access chess24's live videos and legacy Edge for the other two.  I've read that Edge uses more memory than Chrome for streaming but I assume that won't be the case with the new Edge.

Comment: The new Edge *is* Chrome.

Comment: After doing some research, it seems I must be using Windows Media Player since I've never had to install a player.  But apparently all the players are similar in their use of memory (I saw one comment that VLC uses even more of it).

Comment: So I guess it's just a design issue - for some reason the player developers feel that it's harmless to use a GB of RAM if it's available.  Google seems to feel otherwise since it went to a lot of work to avoid the damage caused by dwindling memory.

Answer (score 0):

It must be a problem with your particular video player.
I have tested using VLC, and its memory usage never exceeds 150 MB when playing.

Remember that the main purpose of the encoding of the video on the disk is to
economize on disk space. To play, the video player must prepare the frames
to play in memory. It must also always be in ahead in the frames, since it
may not be possible to create them on the fly.

If your hardware, and especially the graphical card, is not fast enough to keep up
with the frames and their timings, the player may try to compensate by running
ahead. Your player might be overdoing it.

The only solution, if memory is tight, is to try other players.
I would recommend trying VLC first.

Comment: Thanks!  The 150 MB is truly astonishing compared to what happens on my machine.  Was that for DRM content?  I didn't think that decryption used much memory but I want to make sure I'm comparing apples to apples when I figure out how to get more precise measurements of WMP.

Comment: Try also VLC. In Task Manager, Details tab, compare using the column "Working set (memory)".

Comment: Part of the problem is that I've only been checking the memory usage for the individual tabs rather than just WMP.  With chess24, the website takes 800 MB and then another 400 MB for a tiny video window from Twitch.  For Amazon Prime Video, it often takes more than 1 GB but that includes whatever is required for its fancy "X-ray" technology which lets you find out all sorts of things about the video.  Finally, Spectrum still uses Flash, so its heavy use of memory may be related to that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem completely disappeared when the new Edge arrived, using only half the memory of the old.  But a few unrelated processes also are using far less memory, so the old Edge was most likely a victim, not the culprit.

It's easy to say that the system restart required by the new Edge resolved the problem, but the system had previously been restarted (after a crash) without any effect on memory consumption.  I suppose a smooth shutdown was required to resolve the problem, but I know of no good explanation for that.